# Proof of Cauchy Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove something like there exists an element of order $5$ in a group with $625$ elements. How do I do this using basic properties of group theory? Essentially proving cauchy's theorem at the same time.

Comment: But you do know that all orders of elements are divisors of $|G|$?

Comment: Say you find an element $x$ with order $5^k$ where $k>1$. Then just take $x^{5^{k-1}}$.

Comment: Did you only want to consider groups of prime power order, or did you want Cauchy's full theorem on groups of any order?

Answer (score 4):

Let $e \neq g  \in G$. Its order is $n$ where $n | 625 = 5^4$ by [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), so elementary number theory tells us that $n=5^k$ for some $k \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ ($5^0 =1$ is ruled out as $g \neq e$). If $k=1$ we are done. If not, take $g'=g^{5^{k-1}}$ and note that $g'^5 = g^{5^k} = g^n = e$ so we have an element $g'$ of order $5$.

This will work for any group of size that is a positive power of some prime.